# Load webview with large content in a scrollview in android

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I am trying to add a `WebView` and some other `TextView`s in a `ScrollView`. It works fine till the content size is small. But when the content increases (which is to be loaded in `WebView`), it throws an error saying:

> View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 'x' bytes, only 'y' available".

I tried all different flags and all answers on StackOverflow which I could find, but still unable to solve the issue. Is there a way to have a `WebView` inside `ScrollView` or not?

I can't use `hardwareAccelerated` flag, it makes the whole `Activity` slow.

Comment: You should turn off HardwareAcceleration and try once again, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21145043/1237175

Comment: I mentioned that I cannot turn off HardwareAcceleration as it makes the complete activity slow.

Comment: If you put your web view in scrollview then it might be not work. Because web view has its own scrolling functionality so this is not working.

Comment: It works for smaller content. so that's not the problem. I found a solution myself, posting it as an answer please check.

Answer (score 5):

To make it work, I set `ScrollView` and `WebView` property:

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `WebView` Height and Width as `wrap_content`. And Use `ScrollView` For whole layout page so that your `TextView`s can be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` for width and height in the XML.