# Fragment UI freezing on transaction, but works smoothly on reverting same fragment from fragment back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an `activity` where I am showing single `fragment` at a time, total there are three different fragments.
`FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` containing `RecyclerView` and `ThirdFragment` have a `ScrollView`.

The issue is when a fragment get attached in runtime, UI freezes, but custom `OnItemClickListener` listener works fine. When I select any list item of `FirstFragment` it redirect to `SecondFragment`, which is another list view. `SecondFragment` also get freeze. But if I go back using back button, `FirstFragment` works smooth. Similarly when I select `SecondFragment` list item I get redirect to last i.e `ThirdFragment` which is a scroll view which also get freeze and if I come back to `SecondFragment` it starts working smoothly, but If I go back to the  `FirstFragment` and select any list item again and come to `SecondFragment` again UI freezes.

**NOTE:** This issue is only appearing on **OS version 5.0** (lollipop and above) on *4.2.2 Jelly Bean* everything is working good. There is same freezing issue with support library's `TextInputLayout` animation on android *OS version 5.0* but works good on *4.2.2 Jelly Bean*

I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81) of `activity`, three respective `fragments`,  `RecyclerView.Adapter` and custom `OnItemClickListener`

**[ProductActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81#file-productactivity-java)**, **[ProductCategoryFragment.java](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81#file-productcategoryfragment-java)**, **[ProductListFragment.java](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81#file-productlistfragment-java)**, [**ProductDetailFragment.java**](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81#file-productdetailfragment-java), [**ItemClickSupport.java**](https://gist.github.com/omtodkar/ba4f9c4dbfa23935be2775978aacfa81#file-itemclicksupport-java)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDITS**

On `activity` launch I get following logs.

```
04-01 16:28:47.241 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-01 16:28:47.371 32176-32176/com.example.omkar I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.omkar time:77715999
04-01 16:28:47.381 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.omkar for user  0
04-01 16:28:47.391 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.omkar for user  0
04-01 16:28:47.401 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-01 16:28:47.401 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
04-01 16:28:47.431 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
04-01 16:28:47.431 32176-32176/com.example.omkar I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.omkar.userInterface.activity.product.ProductActivity isFragment :false
04-01 16:28:47.431 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
04-01 16:28:47.461 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
04-01 16:28:47.461 32176-32176/com.example.omkar D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-01 16:28:47.491 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/View: View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 10563840 bytes, only 3686400 available
04-01 16:28:47.501 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/View: View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 10563840 bytes, only 3686400 available
04-01 16:28:47.511 32176-32176/com.example.omkar I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.omkar.userInterface.activity.product.ProductActivity
04-01 16:28:47.511 32176-32176/com.example.omkar I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.omkar.userInterface.activity.product.ProductActivity
04-01 16:28:47.531 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/View: View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 10563840 bytes, only 3686400 available
04-01 16:28:47.561 32176-32176/com.example.omkar I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1d12fb86 time:77716194
04-01 16:28:47.921 32176-32176/com.example.omkar W/View: View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 10563840 bytes, only 3686400 available
04-01 16:28:47.961 32176-32191/com.example.omkar I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32383(1734KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(112KB) LOS objects, 9% free, 16MB/18MB, paused 5.876ms total 38.048ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is resolved. It was because I mentioned `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer Found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145043/4387543